# Gluon Error After clearing video service playlist and adding another track

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

```
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528): FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528): Process: com.nopanicaudiocollection, PID: 22528
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.DefaultVideoService.lambda$new$2(DefaultVideoService.java:105)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.DefaultVideoService$$Lambda$3.onChanged(Unknown Source)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:328)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:72)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:232)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:204)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:102)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.nopanicaudiocollection.BasicView.lambda$null$3(BasicView.java:58)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.nopanicaudiocollection.BasicView$$Lambda$4.accept(Unknown Source)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:154)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.nopanicaudiocollection.BasicView.lambda$new$4(BasicView.java:54)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.nopanicaudiocollection.BasicView$$Lambda$1.handle(Unknown Source)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.227: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3761)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3489)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2498)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:57)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$335(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.access$lambda$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$4.get(Unknown Source)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:391)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleView.notifyMouse(MonocleView.java:119)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.notifyMouse(MouseInput.java:314)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.lambda$postMouseEvent$101(MouseInput.java:227)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.access$lambda$3(MouseInput.java)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
11-29 09:16:02.228: E/AndroidRuntime(22528):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

public class BasicView extends View {

Label label = new Label();




public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    ArrayList<String> playList = new ArrayList();
    try {String line;//declare a string to hold each line of the document
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/music.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));//create a new buffered file reader to read a file reader
//use a while loop to read each line and add it to the list
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            playList.add(line);    
        }
        //close the buffered reader
                    br.close();
    }
    //catch block to catach and console print any exceptions
    catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox();
    choiceBox.getItems().addAll(playList);
    choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    Button button = new Button("Set Track");

    button.setOnAction(b -> {
        System.setProperty("com.gluonhq.charm.down.debug", "true");
        Services.get(VideoService.class).ifPresent(video -> {
            video.getPlaylist().clear();
            video.setPosition(Pos.CENTER, 0, 40, 0, 40);
            video.setControlsVisible(false);
            video.getPlaylist().add/*All(Arrays.asList*/(getChoice(choiceBox)/*)*/);
            video.play();


            Button playButton = MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.button();
            playButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                if (video.statusProperty().get() == Status.PLAYING) {
                    playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.graphic());
                    video.pause();
                } else {
                    playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PAUSE.graphic());
                    video.play();
                }
            });

            Button stopButton = MaterialDesignIcon.STOP.button(e -> {
                video.stop();
                video.hide();}
            );

            getApplication().getAppBar().getActionItems().addAll(playButton, stopButton);
            video.statusProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
                if (video.statusProperty().get() == Status.PLAYING) {
                    playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PAUSE.graphic());
                } else {
                    playButton.setGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.PLAY_ARROW.graphic());
                }}); 
        });

    });


    /*Button button = new Button("Change the World!");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LANGUAGE));
    button.setOnAction(e -> label.setText("Hello JavaFX Universe!"));*/

    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, choiceBox, label, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    setCenter(controls);
}

private String getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox) {
    String music = choiceBox.getValue();
    String nowPlaying = "Now Playing: ";
    label.setText(nowPlaying + music);
    return music;
}

@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
    appBar.setTitleText("Audio Collection");
    appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
}

}
```

I have a choice box that is filled by an array from a bufferedreader. That selects the music track. Then the theory is the getter method gets the selection of the choice box, sets the label and converts the selection into a string and returns it. Then the set track button activates the music by setting it up and setting the playlist after clearing the playlist. Now this all works the first time you can select any track and play it. When you stop the music and try to reselect the track you can use the choice box but as soon as you press the set track button again you get the above error. This is a gluon mobile single view project.

Comment: Have you tried reseting the `currentIndex`, like `video.setCurrentIndex(0)`?

Comment: I have just tried that, no luck so far I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Why don't you just add the tracks to the playlist and use `video.setCurrentIndex(index)` to play the selected index? Anyway, if you can post the video service logs from the logcat that would help.

Comment: I've redone the code to be used in the way you suggested and it's got rid of the problem. I have a different problem now but I will do a new question if necessary.